# Using agent forwarding with paramiko on Windows

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to write a python script to execute a number of remote commands on a linux machine from Windows. I am using paramiko as the SSH connection library and running some fab scripts on the remote machine.

However, the fab scripts then connect to other machines so I need to use agent forwarding. However, whenever I run the code I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 117, in run
    raise AuthenticationException("Unable to connect to SSH agent")
```

I have copied verbatim several examples including: https://gist.github.com/toejough/436540622530c35404e6

It looks like I need to set up a local authentication agent as it is just forwarding to nothing, but I can't find out how to do that.

My code:

```
privkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(PrivKeyDirFile, password = PrivKeyPw)

# Start the client
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(hostname = Host, username = User, pkey = privkey)
# get a session
sshChannel = client.get_transport().open_session()
# set up the agent request handler to handle agent requests from the server
paramiko.agent.AgentRequestHandler(sshChannel)  # <--UNDOCUMENTED??!!
# get a shell
sshChannel.get_pty()
sshChannel.invoke_shell()

# SNIP

sshChannel.send

("command-which-invokes-fab-script\n")
# error now happens
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just too much a novice with SSH/paramiko, but I'm confused by everything starting on the line

```
# get a session
```

Why not just have:

```
# Connect the client as before ...
# Run the command:
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('command-which-invokes-fab-script', get_pty = True)
```

Comment: We're running an interactive session which requires sending and listening to a large number of commands. From our reading and experimenting exec_command was more useful for single commands, whereas the channel is more useful for the more interactive method.

Comment: @voiceofthemany - Okay. Do you get the same error when using `exec_command`? If not, you may want to compare the source code for `exec_command` vs what you've written.

Comment: Yes, same error for the "problem" command when using exec_command.

Comment: @voiceofthemany - Hm. Okay. What if you just try using your password instead of doing the whole `pkey` thing? Just trying to zero in on what's actually causing your problem.